# Unable to add icons to action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have recently started a new project and created a custom action bar but for some reason it is not adding icons to it, they will appear on the overflow part but not on the actual bar! :(, really sorry if this seems simple I have just started learning android, I'll post my code below.

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/maps"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_map"
    android:title= "@string/maps"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:orderInCategory="100"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

part of my main method

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Thanks in advance

edit: I'm using android studio as well

edit2: Here is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_maps"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
   >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="SIX REP MAX" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Chest"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Back"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Biceps"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Triceps"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Shoulders"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Legs"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

edit 3: Here is my custom action bar

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#0099FF</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>

</style>
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this for all menu items:

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

and add this to your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    // This will hide the 3-dots menu
    return false;
}
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: Unfortunatly no :(, it appears in the overflow section however, but not on the action bar, thank you for the fast response btw

Comment: Hi thanks again, after adding the method the oveflow just disappears but the icon however still dosent appear :(

Comment: @aluckii: what device or emulator are you using ??

Comment: I'm using my Nexus 5 as a USB

Comment: @aluckii: something else is affecting the way we display the menu icons. I also have a Nexus 5 with me here. If possible, can you share your code with me ? Is it on Github ?

Comment: Yes of course, I will upload my code there now, 2 mins :)

Comment: Hi sorry I am havng issues uploading it to github, I will post my custom styles here on this question as i think this may be where the error is

Comment: @aluckii: I am looking at your code ... so far not able to figure out the problem

Comment: Hi thanks again, I took a break and looked over it again, I decided to change my api to just lollipop and use the material design, the action bar now works perfectly, thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @aluckii: That means the problem was because of API mismatch between project and support library ... anyway, good for you, I'm happy that you could get it to work by yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you should be using , careful look at the return in onCreateOptionsMenu

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.some_menu_xml, menu);

   //return true is important here
    return true;
 }
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.maps:
            //Do Something
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
           //Do Something else
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I have just tried to implement this but I have gotten the same result, it won't appear for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/maps"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_map"
    android:title= "@string/maps"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="100"/>
   <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Probably your image is not fitting to actionbar. So as you are trying

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

Its misplacing. So instead of using ifRoom put always. Otherwise try to make the image resized to fit your action bar

Comment: Hi thank you for the response, I've tried adding the 'always' to the showAsAction but it still does not appear on the action bar. Also i downloaded an icon pack from google, so i would think they would all fit :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems all okay but try removing

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

from `<menu>` tag and also remove

```
android:orderInCategory="100"
```

from `<item android:id="@+id/maps"`

Comment: Hi thanks for the response but unfortunatly this does not solve it :(

Comment: @aluckii Does it show actionbar when you run your app?

Comment: Yes the actionbar is showing, the icon which isn't showing is in the overflow part of the action bar however